# Ionic check condition on app launch

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

i have this two states

```js
.state('app.schedule', {         
url: '/schedule/:course',    

.state('app.home', {       
url: '/home',
onEnter: function() {
// do some magic here
 }

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
```

on app.schedule state i have a method that let a user subscribe to one of a course and its value is saved on cordovaSQLite, now what i want to accomplish is whenever the user has already subscribed to a course the next time s/he launches the app it should load the value(course_id) from cordovaSQLite db then direct the user to app.schedule/:course state. I found 
to use onEnter callback(this doesn't show the flashing transition of view) to check this condition but i cant figure it how to do it correctly. Please help/suggest a way to do this

Comment: Please specify angular and ionic versions!

Comment: i'm using angular v1 and ionic v1. Please help

Comment: any help out there???